# python3 ошибка с replace

Tags: python, replace

Я создал голосового помощника. Когда я спрашиваю, сколько будет 5 умножить на 5, выводится ошибка:

```
 print(f"ассистент: результат - {eval(text.replace('x','*'))}")   File "<string>", line 1
5 х 5
  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вот часть кода:

```
lst = list(query) # принимает слова в массив
l = lst[14::] # берёт срез от "сколько будет"
text = ""
for i in range(len(l)):
    text += l[i]
        
print(f"Ассистент: Результат - {eval(text.replace('x','*'))}")
```

я пытался использовать replace но это не помогает

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Вводится `х` на кириллице, а в коде замена выполняется для английской `x` -- разумеется, `replace` не может найти и заменить английскую букву и возникает синтаксическая ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в тексте у вас "x" русской раскладки, а в replace "x" английской, поэтому и ошибка

Это связано в различии кодовом обозначении "x" в русской раскладке и английской, это связано с использованием разных стандартов кодирования (ASCII для английского и Unicode для многих языков, включая русский) и соответствующими кодами символов для буквы "x" в каждом из этих стандартов.

Используйте модуль "re"

```
import re

lst = list(query) 
l = lst[14::] 
text = "".join(l) 


text = re.sub(r'х', '*', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

result = eval(text)

print(f"ассистент: результат - {result}")
```

Comment: спасибо большое!